# Carousel line break inside menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with carousel inside menu using twitter bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="carousel slide" id="CarouselTest">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav item active" >
                        <li>One 1</li>
                        <li>Two 1</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav item">
                        <li>One 2</li>
                        <li>Two 2</li>

        </ul>


        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                        <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#CarouselTest" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a data-slide="next" href="#CarouselTest" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        </ul>       
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Here an image showing the result i got:
http://www9.0zz0.com/2015/08/02/17/118477064.png

I tried with this but nothing changed:

```
<style>
.carousel-inner{
  width:500px;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

And here demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r8uvfo3s/

If you have any idea about fixing this problem, please give us some help, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match on the image you showed.

Comment: The same problem are exposed :) want to place all things on the same line !!

Comment: Ahh ok, thought of a different issue. Hard to see if only the image makes the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why it seems there's a new line is because there is no space left for the arrows to fit anymore.

To fix that we can use `calc()` to set the appropriate width of `.carousel-inner` to give space for the arrows.

```
.carousel-inner {
    width: calc(100% - 88px); /* 88px the total size of the arrows */
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8uvfo3s/3/)

Update:

Since `calc()` isn't an option, have your `.navbar-right` position absolute instead so it can go up without breaking the `carousel-inner` element.

```
.navbar-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8uvfo3s/4/)

Comment: calc() not help a lot when i have different other categories ! there no way to make it with `width:100%` and depending on other menus ?

Comment: @mombay50 Ok, other solution posted.

Comment: .navbar-right are used in my case to show LOGIN BUTTON and SEARCH BOX this make it not good :/

Comment: @mombay50 Then create a class for that element so you can target that without breaking the other elements. E.g. `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right carousel-navbar-right" >` then on `css` `.carousel-navbar-right { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}`

Comment: as i have two elements then `position:absolute` not solved my problem :/ not an option i think.

Comment: @mombay50 Well, in that case, maybe you should show more code so we can't assume all the time. Can't tell if there will be a problem or not.

Comment: Sorry for this time, here an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/r8uvfo3s/7/ the carousel must e between the TWO1 menu AND Not Move 1 and must cover all the place. :)